# How to do a data.table merge operation

Tags: r, merge, data.table

*note: this question and the following answers refer to data.table versions < 1.5.3; v. 1.5.3 was released in Feb 2011 to resolve this issue.* see more recent treatment (03-2012): [Translating SQL joins on foreign keys to R data.table syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914734/translating-sql-joins-on-foreign-keys-to-r-data-table-syntax)

---

I've been digging through the documentation for the [data.table package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) (a replacement for data.frame that's much more efficient for certain operations), including [Josh Reich's presentation on SQL and data.table at the NYC R Meetup](http://files.meetup.com/1406240/Data%20munging%20with%20SQL%20and%20R.pdf) (pdf), but can't figure this totally trivial operation out.

```
> x <- DT(a=1:3, b=2:4, key='a')
> x
     a b
[1,] 1 2
[2,] 2 3
[3,] 3 4
> y <- DT(a=1:3, c=c('a','b','c'), key='a')
> y
     a c
[1,] 1 a
[2,] 2 b
[3,] 3 c
> x[y]
     a b
[1,] 1 2
[2,] 2 3
[3,] 3 4
> merge(x,y)
  a b c
1 1 2 a
2 2 3 b
3 3 4 c
```

The docs say "When [the first argument] is itself a data.table, a join is invoked similar to base::merge but uses binary search on the sorted key." Clearly this is not the case. Can I get the other columns from y into the result of x[y] with data.tables? It seems like it's just taking the rows of x where the key matches the key of y, but ignoring the rest of y entirely...

Comment: This was resolved by v1.5.3 released to CRAN in Feb 2011. Please see it's NEWS, new ?data.table and corrected FAQ.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are quoting the wrong part of documentation. If you have a look at the doc of `[.data.table` you will read:

> When i is a data.table, x must have a
>   key, meaning join i to x and **return
>   the rows in x that match**. An equi-join
>   is performed between each column in i
>   to each column in x’s key in order.
>   This is similar to base R
>   functionality of sub- setting a matrix
>   by a 2-column matrix, and in higher
>   dimensions subsetting an n-dimensional
>   array by an n-column matrix

I admit the description of the package (the part you quoted) is somewhat confusing, because it seems to say that the "["-operation can be used instead of merge. But I think what it says is: if x and y are both data.tables we use a join on an index (which is invoked like merge) instead of binary search.

---

*One more thing:*

The data.table library I installed via `install.packages` was missing the `merge.data.table method`, so using `merge` would call `merge.data.frame`. After installing the [package from R-Forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/datatable/) R used the faster `merge.data.table` method.

You can check if you have the merge.data.table method by checking the output of:

```
methods(generic.function="merge")
```

---

**EDIT [Answer no longer valid]:** This answer refers to data.table version 1.3. In version 1.5.3 the behaviour of data.table changed and x[y] returns the expected results. Thank you [Matthew Dowle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403310/matthew-dowle), author of data.table, for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: Ah. It appears as if the version on CRAN is version 1.2, while the version on R-Forge is version 1.3. The `merge` method was apparently added in 1.3. From what I can tell looking around R-Forge, the method was added something like 8 months ago, so I don't know why it's not on CRAN yet!

Comment: X[Y] syntax was changed in v1.5.3 released to CRAN in Feb 2011. Please see it's NEWS, new ?data.table and corrected FAQ.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for the answers. I missed this thread when it was originally posted. data.table has moved on since February. 1.4.1 was released to CRAN a while ago and 1.5 is out soon. For example the DT() alias has been replaced with list(); as a primitive its much faster, and data.table now inherits from data.frame so it works with packages that *only* accept data.frame such as ggplot and lattice, without any conversion required (faster and more convenient).

Is it possible to subscribe to the data.table tag so I get an email when someone posts a question with that tag?  The datatable-help list has grown to about 30-40 messages a month, but I'm happy to answer here too if I can get some kind of notification.

Matthew

Answer (score 13):

I think using the `base::merge` function is not needed, as using `data.table` joins can be a lot faster. E.g. see the following. I make `x` and `y` data.tables with 3-3 columns:

```
x <- data.table( foo = 1:5, a=20:24, zoo = 5:1 )
y <- data.table( foo = 1:5, b=30:34, boo = 10:14)
setkey(x, foo)
setkey(y, foo)
```

And merge both with `base:merge` and `data.table` joins to see the speed of executions:

```
system.time(merge(x,y))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   0.027   0.000   0.023 

system.time(x[,list(y,x)])
##    user  system elapsed 
##   0.003   0.000   0.006
```

The results are not identical, as the latter has one extra column:

```
merge(x,y)
##      foo  a zoo  b boo
## [1,]   1 20   5 30  10
## [2,]   2 21   4 31  11
## [3,]   3 22   3 32  12
## [4,]   4 23   2 33  13
## [5,]   5 24   1 34  14

x[,list(x,y)]
##      foo  a zoo foo.1  b boo
## [1,]   1 20   5     1 30  10
## [2,]   2 21   4     2 31  11
## [3,]   3 22   3     3 32  12
## [4,]   4 23   2     4 33  13
## [5,]   5 24   1     5 34  14
```

Which could not make a big trouble :)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. An entirely unobvious syntax, though! If I were to use that, I might redefine a function that does `function(x,y) x[,list(x,y)]` or something, perhaps dropping that extra key column too...

Comment: I think the proper syntax for joins in data.table is actually x[y] or x[y,], i.e. joins should use the first index.  This gives the same results as merge.  note that x[y] and y[x] need not be identical, i.e. if y contains entries in foo that are not representative of x.  Maybe I've missed somehting, but see Joins in the data.table [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf)

Comment: the above x[,list(x,y)] did not work for me. I tried x[,c(x,y)] and it worked. I am not sure if it makes sense though.

Comment: After using setkey, you can just do  x[y]

Answer (score 3):

I think that f3lix is correct and that the documentation is a little misleading.  The benefit is in doing a fast join to subset the data.  You still ultimately need to use the `merge` function afterwards as in your above example.

You will see in [Josh's presentation on using data.table](http://files.meetup.com/1406240/Data%20munging%20with%20SQL%20and%20R.pdf) that this is how his example runs.  He first subsets one of the data.tables, then does a merge:

```
library(data.table)
sdt <- DT(series, key='series_id')
ddt <- DT(data, key='series_id')
u <- sdt[ grepl('^[A-Z]{2}URN', fred_id) & !grepl('DSURN', fred_id) ]
d <- ddt[ u, DT(min=min(value)), by='series_id', mult='all']
data <- merge(d,series)[,c('title','min','mean','max')]
```