# R: When using data.table how do I get columns of y when I do x[y]?

Tags: r, data.table

***UPDATE***: Old question ... it was resolved by data.table v1.5.3 in Feb 2011.

I am trying to use the `data.table` package, and really like the speedups I am getting, but I am stumped by this error when I do `x[y, <expr>]` where `x` and `y` are "data-tables" with the same key, and `<expr>` contains column names of both `x` and `y`:

```
require(data.table)
x <- data.table( foo = 1:5, a = 5:1 )
y <- data.table( foo = 1:5, boo = 10:14)
setkey(x, foo)
setkey(y, foo)
> x[y, foo*boo]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'boo' not found
```

UPDATE...
To clarify the functionality I am looking for in the above example: I need to do the equivalent of the following:

```
with(merge(x,y), foo*boo)
```

However according to the below extract from the `data.table` FAQ, this should have worked:

> Finally, although it appears as though
>   x[y] does not return the columns in y,
>   you can actually use the columns from
>   y in the j expression. This is what we
>   mean by join inherited scope. Why not
>   just return the union of all the
>   columns from x and y and then run
>   expressions on that? It boils down to
>   eciency of code and what is quicker
>   to program. When you write
>   x[y,foo*boo], data.table automatically
>   inspects the j expression to see which
>   columns it uses. It will only subset,
>   or group, those columns only. Memory
>   is only created for the columns the j
>   uses. Let's say foo is in x, and boo
>   is in y (along with 20 other columns
>   in y). Isn't x[y,foo*boo] quicker to
>   program and quicker to run than a
>   merge step followed by another subset
>   step ?

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232699/r-how-to-do-a-data-table-merge-operation) that addressed a similar issue, but it did not seem to have been resolved satisfactorily. Anyone know what I am missing or misunderstanding? Thanks.

UPDATE: I asked on the data-table help mailing list and the package author (Matthew Dowle) [replied](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Cannot-access-cols-of-y-when-doing-x-y-tt3231504.html) that indeed the FAQ quoted above is wrong, so the syntax I am using will not work currently, i.e. I cannot refer to the `y` columns in the `j` (i.e. second) argument when I do `x[y,...]`.

Comment: But you asked some time ago and it was addressed by v1.5.3 released to CRAN in Feb 2011. Please see it's NEWS, new ?data.table and corrected FAQ.

Comment: @Matthew thank you, yes I know it's been addressed by the latest release, and I'm glad you pointed it out here so it's clear to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the problem well, and I also just started to read the docs of *data.table* library, but I think if you would like to get the columns of *y* and also do something to those by the columns of *a*, you might try something like:

```
> x[y,a*y]
     foo boo
[1,]   5  50
[2,]   8  44
[3,]   9  36
[4,]   8  26
[5,]   5  14
```

Here, you get back the columns of *y* multiplied by the *a* column of *x*. If you want to get *x*'s *foo* multiplied by *y*'s *boo*, try:

```
> y[,x*boo]
     foo  a
[1,]  10 50
[2,]  22 44
[3,]  36 36
[4,]  52 26
[5,]  70 14
```

---

**After editing:** thank you @Prasad Chalasani making the question clearer for me.

If simple merging is preferred, then the following should work. I made up a more complex data to see the actions deeper:

```
x <- data.table( foo = 1:5, a=20:24, zoo = 5:1 )
y <- data.table( foo = 1:5, b=30:34, boo = 10:14)
setkey(x, foo)
setkey(y, foo)
```

So only an extra column was added to each data.table. Let us see `merge` and doing it with `data.tables`:

```
> system.time(merge(x,y))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.027   0.000   0.023 
> system.time(x[,list(y,x)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.003   0.000   0.006
```

From which the latter looks a lot faster. The results are not identical though, but can be used in the same way (with an extra column of the latter run):

```
> merge(x,y)
     foo  a zoo  b boo
[1,]   1 20   5 30  10
[2,]   2 21   4 31  11
[3,]   3 22   3 32  12
[4,]   4 23   2 33  13
[5,]   5 24   1 34  14
> x[,list(x,y)]
     foo  a zoo foo.1  b boo
[1,]   1 20   5     1 30  10
[2,]   2 21   4     2 31  11
[3,]   3 22   3     3 32  12
[4,]   4 23   2     4 33  13
[5,]   5 24   1     5 34  14
```

So to get `xy` we might use: `xy <- x[,list(x,y)]`. To compute a one-column data.table from `xy$foo * xy$boo`, the following might work:

```
> xy[,foo*boo]
[1] 10 22 36 52 70
```

Well, the result is not a data.table but a vector instead.

---

**Update (29/03/2012):** thanks for @David for pointing my attention to the fact that `merge.data.table` were used in the above examples.

Comment: Referring to the example in my question, I want to do a join of `x` and `y`, let's call it `xy`, and then create a single-column data-frame that is equal to `xy$foo * xy$boo`.

Comment: @Prasad Chalasani: I edited my answer, I hope you can find something new and valuable in it.

Comment: thanks for the details, but my question was about why the specific syntax I describe in my question is not working, contrary to what it says in the FAQ. I know that I can do it in two stages (merge, then operate on columns), but I want the `x[y, <expr>]` syntax to work *in one step* -- i.e. do the join and operate on the `x` and `y` columns in one step. This is syntactically less tedious, and possibly faster (if implemented right internally). I am dealing with 10-million row data-frames, so I'm not concerned with the timings of the small toy example above.

Comment: @Prasad Chalasani: I see, then my "answer" seems to be no answer :( I suppose the FAQ is just not correct at that part, as @f3lix suggested.

Comment: This was resolved by v1.5.3 released to CRAN in Feb 2011. Please see it's NEWS, new ?data.table and corrected FAQ.

Comment: isn't your example using `merge.data.table` and not `base::merge`?

Comment: Thanks @David, I think *now* you are right. Will update that answer.